# google api oauth access token retrieval - 400 bad request

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api

I'm trying to retrieve the oauth access token to make calls to some google apis in asp.net mvc, and I wrote the following code for an action:

```
        public ActionResult GetOAuthToken()
        {

        String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Host = "accounts.google.com";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = String.Format("code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type=authorization_code", Request.QueryString["code"].ToString(), OAuthConfig.client_id, OAuthConfig.client_secret, OAuthConfig.token_redirect_uri);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        // SOME CODE TO PROCESS THE RESPONSE

        Response.Redirect("/Home");
        return View();
        }
```

OAuthConfig is just a class that contains the client id, client secret etc.

I keep getting 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' at the request.GetResponse() line. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is there a response body? What does it say?

Comment: There is none. An exception is thrown at the line request.GetResponse()

Comment: There almost certainly is. Catch the WebException and check out its properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx

Comment: I did examine the WebException using the debugger, but I didn't find anything useful there. Where exactly do you find the response body?

Comment: `catch(WebException ex){ var response = ex.Response; ...}`? If it's non-null, decode the response stream. It could contain more info.

Comment: I tried the approach above in the msdn article, and this is what I got - Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Status Code : BadRequest Bad Request: Status Description : {0}

Comment: The reason for a `400 - Bad Request` is malformed data. Something is broken in your request. Check your post values for invalid characters.

Comment: I'm getting the authorization code from google, and the values for the client_id and client_secret I copied from the API console and pasted them as public const strings into my OAuthConfig class. I've also listed the redirect_uri in the API console and copied and pasted that too. I even ran the debugger and checked the value of postData, and it was exactly as expected. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

Google does provide a higher level library to work with its services, this handles the formatting of the urls and I find it makes it a lot easier to work with their apis. See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

Comment: I tried using the .net library but there weren't any clear tutorials on how to simply get the access token if you already have the authorization code. I saw the sample code posted here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2 too but it was in the context of a simple client application. I didn't know how to translate the code in my scenario, where I have the authorization code in a query string.